# How to handle Decimal(38,17) Datatype length in ASP/MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to handle this Datatype length in ASP or MVC.NET Code.

```
Declare @test Decimal(38,17)
Set @test = 1234567891234567891234567.1234567894561
Select @test
```

Comment: it's very interesting to me when the requirements of such high precision decimals questions are asked, do you mind sharing your use case? Most of the time you don't need such high precision

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `double` and a `decimal` do not offer enough precision for your task, could you make use of [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782)?

> BigRational builds on the BigInteger introduced in .NET Framework 4 to create an arbitrary-precision rational number type.